# florence virtual keyboard missing from 22.04 LTS

Tags: onscreen-keyboard

Florence virtual keyboard is missing from 22.04 LTS and the in built virtual keyboard in Ubuntu is only working in very few applications. It makes 22.04 unsuitable for tablets/touch screens.

**It was packaged for Ubuntu as recently as 20.04 LTS
https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=florence&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all**

Any plans of releasing a package with Florence for 22.04 LTS?

Official site of Florence;
http://florence.sourceforge.net/english.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: Thanks, no not really. The version is not old. There is no version available at all.

Comment: In your question you wrote "Any plans of releasing a package with Florence for 22.04 LTS?" and inserted a link to Florence at http://florence.sourceforge.net/english.html. If your question is not a duplicate, it's unclear.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Not sure what part is unclear but I have edited my original post in an attempt to clear things up.